# How to replace parts of formula in excel?

Tags: excel

1. I have in first column this:

   =SUM('\Y2022[Salaries_combined_01.2021-08.2022.xlsx]report'!$**ND**$353:$**NG**$353)
2. In the second column the formula should look like this

   =SUM('\Y2022[Salaries_combined_01.2021-08.2022.xlsx]report'!$**NV**$353:$**NY**$353)
3. How to replace only columns "ND" -> "NV" and "NG" -> "NY" at once, automatically and not by hand with (Ctrl + H)?

Comment: If you have a formula in one colum and drag&drop the formula to the next column Excel will automatically change the columns of the formulas to the next one (unless you put a `$` to fix the column). Now here you are moving from the first column to the second, and you want to jump 3 columns in the formula `ND` -> `NG`.  There's no way Excel could know you want 3 columns instead of 1. Just change by hand the first row and drag&drop to update automatically the rest of the rows

Answer (score 0):

A technique I use is to do the following:

1. select column or range and replace "=" with xyxyxy
2. edit replace "ND" with "NV", repeat for "NG" "NY"
3. then replace xyxyxy with =

Works well as each change does not cause errors as removing the = makes all the cell entries text...